# Device Location on Actions on Google

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Currently, I have an application setup to prompt the user for their location upon first use of the application.  If the user gives permission, then I get the location and store it.  However, if the user is on the phone and moves, I don't get the location in the second "conversation".

Do I have to request the location for each "conversation", or is requesting permission one time enough, and I am just not doing something else properly.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, yes, you will need to request it every time.

(This is a frequent complaint, and the team is aware of our desire to handle this better, but this is how it is right now.)